# Hue 500 server error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop2, hue

I am creating a MapReduce simple job. After submitting, its giving below error [image: Hue error]

Suggest to fix this issue

Comment: Is your HDFS up? e.g. does File Browser let you create a file

Comment: Yes it is up and running

Comment: Any update @Romain

Answer (score -1):

I know I am too late to answer. But I have noticed that this usually gets solved if you clear your cookies.