# Server Error 500 when accessing HUE

Tags: hadoop, hue

I’ve installed the latest HUE version 3.11. However whenever I try and access Hue via http://localhost:8888 it constantly gives me Server Error 500.

[image]

I’ve looked at the logs and both runcpserver.log and supervisor.log indicate that everything looks OK. I’ve tried removing the hue directory and re running make install but its the same every time.

Here's the output from some of the logs:

runcpserver.log:

```
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:02 -0700] __init__     WARNING  Couldn't import snappy.     Support for snappy compression disabled.
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:03 -0700] settings     INFO     Welcome to Hue 3.11.0
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:04 -0700] __init__     WARNING  Couldn't import snappy.     Support for snappy compression disabled.
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:31 -0700] middleware   INFO     Unloading  AuditLoggingMiddleware
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:31 -0700] middleware   INFO     Unloading SpnegoMiddleware
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:31 -0700] middleware   INFO     Unloading HueRemoteUserMiddleware
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:33 -0700] decorators   INFO     AXES: BEGIN LOG
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:33 -0700] decorators   INFO     Using django-axes 1.5.0
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:33 -0700] middleware   INFO     Redirecting to login page: /
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:33 -0700] access       INFO     192.168.56.72 -anon- - "GET / HTTP/1.1" -- login redirection
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:33 -0700] fsmanager    WARNING  Filesystem not configured for s3a
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:34 -0700] decorators   INFO     AXES: Calling decorated function: dt_login
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:35 -0700] decorators   INFO     AXES: Calling decorated function: dt_login
[20/Oct/2016 04:10:35 -0700] decorators   INFO     args: (True,)
```

supervisor.log:

```
20/Oct/2016 12:09:51 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[20/Oct/2016 12:09:51 ] supervisor   INFO     Starting process /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[20/Oct/2016 12:09:51 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 25860) /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer
[20/Oct/2016 12:09:51 ] supervisor   INFO     Started proceses (pid 25861) /usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
[20/Oct/2016 12:10:03 ] supervisor   INFO     Command "/usr/local/hue/build/env/bin/hue kt_renewer" exited normally.
```

access.log:

```
[20/Oct/2016 04:25:49 -0700] INFO     192.168.56.72 -anon- - "GET / HTTP/1.1" -- login redirection
[20/Oct/2016 04:25:49 -0700] DEBUG    192.168.56.72 -anon- - "GET  /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1"
[20/Oct/2016 04:25:50 -0700] DEBUG    192.168.56.72 -anon- - "GET /static/desktop/ext/fonts/Roboto-regular/Roboto-regular.f84cb1bf9be9.woff2  HTTP/1.1"
[20/Oct/2016 04:25:52 -0700] DEBUG    192.168.56.72 -anon- - "GET /static/desktop/art/favicon.2351422f4956.ico HTTP/1.1"
```

I should also add that this is a standalone installation of HUE and not via CDH. However I've managed to get it working before this way so don't see this as being a deal breaker.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error log on Hue web UI

Comment: I've added some log info from /usr/local/hue/logs I can't really see anything wrong here. Maybe there are other logs I'm unaware of.

Comment: Are you getting anything like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207387/hue-500-server-error?rq=1

Comment: Yes, however I don't see all the log info or file names below the error. I've also tried clearing cookies in Firefox but I still get the same error consistently.

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix this by simply installing Hue 3.10 instead of 3.11

Thanks.